# inserting a checkbox into a text box, python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter, textbox

As the title says I want to have a checkbox inserted into a text box. I have tried and searched ALOT of different ways I could think of and nothing is working. Any help is greatly appreciated!
I'm not going to list every way I tried otherwise this page would be incredibly long.

The following code is just an example without the checkbox.

```
import tkinter as tk
self = tk.Tk()
TEXT_BOX = tk.Text(self, width = 20, height = 10)
TEXT_BOX.pack()
app = self
app.mainloop()
```

Also this is the checkbox I wanted to use, i just cant figure out how to insert it.

```
var1 = tk.IntVar()
TEST = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable = var1)
```

If you know of a better method please let me know.

Solved thanks to Bryan. The working code is;

```
import tkinter as tk
self = tk.Tk()
TEXT_BOX = tk.Text(self, width = 20, height = 10)
TEXT_BOX.pack()
var1 = tk.IntVar()
TEST = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable = var1)
TEXT_BOX.window_create("1.0", window = TEST)
TEXT_BOX.insert("end", "\n")
app = self
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of giving instructions how to simulate your data, you should take the time to rewrite your example so that we don't have to. Also, you say you've tri d lots of things but I don't see anything that attempts to create a checkbutton.

Comment: updated the code and statement. l

Comment: -let me know if it helps you. Accidentally hit the add comment button before i was done.

Comment: It doesn't help. It still requires an external file, and still doesn't show any attempt at creating checkboxes.  Why can't you just hard-code a couple of rows of data? Also, consider removing the option menu and the search box, if all you're asking about is how to add checkbuttons to a text widget. See the following link for how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I gave that specific code to help give the idea as to how my main code is structured but I can can break it all down to just a text box if it helps people. Also I'm still fairly new to Python so how would I hard code searchable data?

Comment: Yeah, we don't particularly care about your main code. We want the smallest amount of code possible that helps to illustrate your actual problem. If you're asking how to add checkboxes to a text widget, you need a text widget, and some sort of loop that adds data with checkboxes. Not much more. To hard code data, just create a list (or list of lists). `data = [["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2"], ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2"], ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a checkbutton (or any widget) into a text widget, use the documented method `window_create`.

Example:

```
TEXT_BOX.window_create("1.0", window=TEST)
TEXT_BOX.insert("end", "<-- a checkbox!\n")
```

This is mentioned in the text widget documentation (eg: `help(tk.Text)`) as well as many popular tutorials:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm
- http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html
- http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

Comment: Your method works perfectly, also I have bookmarked those pages and will look through them closely, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The below shows an example of how you can create a number of `CheckButtons` and then cleanly check which ones have been selected:

```
from tkinter import * #imports tkinter

root = Tk() #sets root as the Tk window

examples = 10 #sets the number of example to create

label = [] #empty array for storing labels
checkbox = [] #empty array for storing checkboxes
array = [] #empty array for storing checkbox boolean states

for i in range(examples): #for loop for creating the contents of the page
    array.append(BooleanVar()) #adds an empty tk booleans value to array
    label.append(Label(root, text="Example: "+str(i))) #creates a label
    label[i].grid(column=0, row=i) #grids the above label
    checkbox.append(Checkbutton(root, variable=array[i])) #creates a button. the state variable for the button is stored in the next element of the array
    checkbox[i].grid(column=1, row=i) #grids button

def command(): #command executed from button below
    for i in range(examples): #for loop for each example
        if array[i].get() == True: #checks if the button is ticked (True)
            print("Example "+str(i)+" is ticked.") #prints this if the button is ticked
        else:
            print("Example "+str(i)+" is not ticked.") #prints this if the button is not ticked

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command) #creates a button to process the output

button.grid() #grids button

root.mainloop() #starts event loop
```

This creates an array where in each `element` is tied to the `boolean` state of the relevant `checkbutton`. The program then uses a `for` loop to run through the array and prints the results based on an `if` loop which checks against the `boolean` states of each `checkbutton`.

A similar principle could be applied for what you are looking for although obviously instead of printing a useless statement you'd take some sort of action against your data.

Comment: This is a very good example that is very informative and it will help me greatly with my next part but how would I get those check boxes into a text box?

Comment: As in an `entry` widget?

Comment: Yeah sorry if I wasn't very specific. Like for example Im trying to get the checkboxes into a Text feild.